# How is Storyboard.TargetName implemented?

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom ToolTip that needs to get a reference to another control.  It's very similar to how Storyboard.TargetName would work.  Now I've rolled my own implementation on how to get the target reference such as (note that my target will always be a parent of the ToolTip):

```
public object FindTarget(string targetName)
{
    var target = default(object);
    FrameworkElement item = this;
    while ((item = item.Parent as FrameworkElement) != null && target == null)
        target = item.FindName(targetName);
    return target;
}
```

My question is is there a way to do this that's built into the framework?  It seems like this is a common enough task that it would be.

**Edit**:

Turns out the above algorithm doesn't actually work for ToolTips because their Parent property is always null. I'm assuming ToolTips are based on Popups and this is why the Parent is null.

Answer (score -1):

You can use extension methods to make it visible from anywhere you want:

```
public static object GetElementByName(this FrameworkElement baseElement, string name) 
    {
        object target = null;

        FrameworkElement item = baseElement;
        while ((item = item.Parent as FrameworkElement) != null && target == null)
            target = item.FindName(name);

        return target;
    }
```

After this you are able to call this method on any FrameworkElement.
Although you should be aware of the fact that FindName will not work for names defined in Templates.

Comment: Right, but this was not a question about extension methods.  I'm simply hoping there was a baked-in way to do this.  Not because I want to use it everywhere, but I don't want to repeat something that may already be implemented / properly handles edge cases that I haven't yet considered.